# Creating and updating appointments in Exchange

Tags: c#, exchange-server, webdav

I'm trying to implement creating/updating appointments via C# code. I'm using dedicated exchange account and webdav to communicate. Updating appointment require saving this appointment to our tech-user mailbox.
Is there any other option to create and update appointments? Right now I'm struggling limits in quantity of calendar appointment on single mailbox.
I'm sure there should be other option but I can not see it.

Looking to see if anyone else has any suggestions or solutions to this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Creating an appointment...
//Give values to Subject,body,....
_service is the Exchange service object.

```
Appointment app = new Appointment(_service);
        app.Subject = subject;
        app.Body = body;
        app.Start = startTime;
        app.End = endTime;
        app.Location = location;

        DayOfTheWeek[] days = new DayOfTheWeek[] { DayOfTheWeek.Saturday };
        app.Recurrence = new Recurrence.WeeklyPattern(app.Start.Date, 1, days);
        app.Recurrence.StartDate = app.Start.Date;
        app.Recurrence.NumberOfOccurrences = 3;

        app.Save();
```

If you need further information please ask...